# Java compiler not creating .jar files

Tags: java, compilation

I have a small java program written in Eclipse Oxygen (with a single class called `Main`) that works in Eclipse as expected. I tried to compile it using `javac Main.java`. The problem is that the java compiler doesn't throw any errors and seems to recognize the command, but doesn't create a .jar file of any kind anywhere. I tried setting the classpath manually (although this shouldn't be necessary) but the result was the same.

Update: I was (or still am) a noob and didn't understand what `javac` does. It was pointed out to me that `javac` only creates `.class` files, which it actually did when I used it, so there was no "wrong behavior" or error of any kind. Look at the answers if you want to know how to create `.jar` files in Eclipse.

Comment: what makes you think compiling a file will/should create a jar?

Comment: `javac` creates class files, not jar files.

Comment: compiling a java file will only give you a .class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest assured: there are no silent errors.

When a tool like `javac` fails it **will** print some error message to the standard "error" console.

Thing is:

```
javac Main.java
```

will simply create a file `Main.class` within the same directory.

Which you could try to run using `java Main`.

That is all there is to this. Well, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for all the glory details of javac.

Answer (score 2):

Hey if you want create a jar file in eclipse just right click on the respective project and select export:
1)A dialog box will appear 
2)Now type jar in the text area and select runnable jar 
3)click next and then fill the jar name and the path where you want to create a jar.

OR
 if you want to do it by cmd use the below code at the file location in cmd

```
jar cfve file.jar Main Main.class Main$1.class Main$2.class
```